# Mistake x AS y, or mistake x FOR y?

Tags: prepositions

- > Don't mistake my confidence **for** arrogance
- > Don't mistake my confidence **as** arrogance

Is "for" or "as" more appropriate in the sentence?

Answer (score 4):

The following definition of **for** is now obsolete, but it survives in few expressions like this one.

[image]
[image]

So in your example *mistake my confidence **for** arrogance* and *mistake my confidence **as** arrogance* both equivalent in meaning. They mean the same thing. But **mistake my confidence for arrogance** is idiomatic.

<sub>Definition reference - Oxford English Dictionary (OED)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The expression "mistake X **for** Y" takes "for". It is simply set like that as a *phrasal verb*.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mistake-for

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mistake-sb-sth-for-sb-sth

To "mistake X for Y" means that you **wrongly identified** X (which is what the thing actually is) as Y (which is what the person thought X was).

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mistake?s=t (sense 3)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistake (transitive verb sense 3)

**However, you can use "as" to as part of the "misinterpret as" meaning.**

> I mistook your exam score as how well you were performing this semester.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mistake

Answer (score 1):

> Don't mistake my confidence for arrogance.
>
> Don't mistake my confidence as arrogance.

I think there's no difference in meaning between these sentences.  When you misunderstand or misjudge someone or something to be someone or something else, you can use either "as" or "for" after the verb "mistake," but the use of "for" is more common.  Look at the following sentences:

I mistook her offer as a threat (Oxford).

He mistook my politeness for friendliness (The Free Dictionary).

I think "as" and "for" are interchangeable in these sentences.

The use of "for" is also more appropriate when you confuse someone or something with someone or something else, for example, *he mistook me for your brother.*

Comment: Can somebody provide corpus results? I cannot find an "as" example in a dictionary. (I tried 9 dictionaries) And a couple of dictionaries have "mistake for" as its own entry as a phrasal verb while "mistake as" lacks an entry.

Comment: Oh. I found that "mistake for" and "mistake as" are separate types of constructions entirely.

http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/mistake

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mistake_2

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mistake